# How would i print this on the same line

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that builds a "building" using multiple characters.
There are 3 functions:

```
  1. int ValidateData(int low, int high, char type)
```

This function validates that the user's entry meets the required parameters and returns the correct number depending on the `type` parameter.

No problems here.

2. `int drawUpperFloors(int numOfWindows)`

This function is supposed to draw the number of floors depending on how many windows the user entered. My problem is that I cannot seem to get the windows to draw on the same line. If the user entered 3 the output should be: (Took awhile to get that right)

`+---------------+
|               |
|  === === ===  |
|  | | | | | |  |
|  === === ===  |
|               |`

Instead I get a window on a new line until the loop reaches its limit (`numOfWindows`), so if `numOfWindows`= 20 then I get 20 windows each on a different line. I would appreciate insight into how I might do this.

3. `void DrawGroundFloor(int numOfWindows)`

   This function is almost identical to the `drawUpperFloors( )` function
   except that the first window will be replaced with a door.
   So, if the numOfWindows parameter is 2, then the ground floor will consist
   of 1 door and 1 window.
   If the number of windows is only 1, then only a door will be drawn.

   Please take note of the following details:
   a). Each window (and door) is exactly 3 columns wide.

   b). The bottom of the floor is drawn using the * character.

   An example of a ground floor with 5 windows woulb be:

`+-----------------------+
|                       |
|  === === === === ===  |
|  | | | | | | | | | |  |
|  | | === === === ===  |
|  | |                  |
*************************`

Considering I have been unable to do the second function this comes as no surprise.

I have tried using up to 3 loops using `if` and `else`, but I still cannot, no matter what I try (even modulus) get it print in the same line.
Any input would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
here's the code for the 2 functions so far

```
int GetValidData(int low, int high, char type)
{
    int number;
    int number2;

    int i=1;
    int j;
    if (type == 'F')
    {
        printf("Enter the amount of floors you would like(1-1000)\n");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        fflush(stdin);


        if (number < 1 || number>1000)
        {
            while(i!=0)
            {
                printf("You have entered an invalid floor number\nPlease enter a valid number: ");

                scanf("%d", &number);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (number >= 1 && number <= 1000)
                {
                    printf("Thank you!\n");
                    i = 0;

                }
            }

        }
        return number;
    }



    printf("Enter the amount of windows you would like(1-20)\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);


    if (type == 'W')
    {
        if (number < 1 || number>20)
        {
            while(i!=0)
            {
                printf("You have entered an invalid number\nPlease enter a valid number: ");
                scanf("%d", &number);
                if (number >= 1 && number <= 20)
                {
                    printf("Thank You!\n");
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        return number;




int drawUpperFloors(int numOfWindows)
{
    int check = numOfWindows;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i <= numOfWindows;i++)
    {
        printf("===\n");
        for (j = 0; j <= numOfWindows;j++)
        {
            printf("|  |\n");
        }

        printf("===");
    }
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something with meaning. It's clear you're looking for assistance, or you wouldn't be posting here, so saying so in your title is not necessary. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking, in a way that will be meaningful to future readers here who see it in a search result. Also, asking for help with your code requires that you post the relevant code in the question, in the form of a [mcve]. Add that when you make the title edit.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code does not compile. It's missing closing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *My problem is that I cannot seem to get the windows to draw on the same line.*

The basic problem is you're adding newlines to your print statements when drawing an individual window.

```
for (i = 0; i <= numOfWindows;i++)
{
    /* There shouldn't be a newline here */
    printf("===\n");
    for (j = 0; j <= numOfWindows;j++)
    {
        /* Nor a newline here */
        printf("|  |\n");
    }

    printf("===");
}
```

You're also counting your windows from 0 which results in one too many windows. Either start from 1 or go until `i < numOfWindows`.

You have to draw each line in its own loop, including the outer walls, ending with a newline. First the upper sills, then the windows, then the lower sills.

```
void drawUpperFloors(int numOfWindows)
{
    int i;

    /* Draw the upper sills, including the outer walls */
    printf("|  ");
    for (i = 1; i <= numOfWindows;i++)
    {
        printf("=== ");
    }
    printf(" |\n");

    /* Draw the windows, including the outer walls */
    printf("|  ");
    for (i = 1; i <= numOfWindows;i++)
    {
        printf("| | ");
    }
    printf(" |\n");

    /* Draw the lower sills, including the outer walls */
    printf("|  ");
    for (i = 1; i <= numOfWindows;i++)
    {
        printf("=== ");
    }
    printf(" |\n");
}
```

That gets repetitive, so it's best to put drawing a line of a floor into a function.

```
void drawFloorLine(int num, const char *to_repeat) {
    int i;

    printf("|  ");
    for (i = 1; i <= num;i++)
    {
        printf("%s", to_repeat);
    }
    printf(" |\n");
}

void drawUpperFloors(int numOfWindows)
{
    drawFloorLine(numOfWindows, "=== ");    
    drawFloorLine(numOfWindows, "| | ");
    drawFloorLine(numOfWindows, "=== ");
}
```

Comment: WOW! You, sir, are a genius. This entire time I was thinking that there was some sort of trick to it. Not thinking that I should just write the lines 1 at a time. Using your `drawFloorLine()` function I seem to be unable to recreate it so that it's usable with `drawGroundFloor()`, but I am still testing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You an use `drawFloorLine()` to draw the first two lines of the ground floor, then you'll have to special case the rest. As for being able to draw multiple lines at once, you want to look at something like [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) which lets you move a cursor around the screen to create text-based user interfaces.